How can I declare a ring in Singular CAS with variable names coming from a list of strings?
The following code constructs a list of strings
list l = ("x1", "x2", "x3"); 

Now I want to declare a ring with variables x1, x2, x3, making use of the existing list l. If this is implemented, I can easily declare, for example, the ring of regular functions on the space of 5$\times$5 symmetric matrices.
The following fail the aim.

ring R = 0, l, lp;  The ring has one variable named l. However l is still the list and polynomial expressions such as poly f = l+1; lead to errors.
ring R = 0, (l), lp; The same as above.

